# confusion matrix in Latex with rotated labels

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to make the table below:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Actual}}
& Yes  & 100 & 0   \\ 
& No  & 10   & 80 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, this gives me:

[image]

Notice that the labels "Predicted" and "actual" are not centered with the columns/rows below/right. In addition, the horizontal lines should stop before the "actual" label. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted}` instead of only 1, because you want it to span more than one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few ways to achive the desired result. I highly recommened using the `booktabs` pacakge and avoid vertical lines (as per third example):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ \hline
\multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
& Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
& No  & 10   & 80 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad% ---------------------------
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc|cc@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
& Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
& No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}

\par\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc cc@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Yes} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{No} \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\multirow[c]{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{Actual}}
& Yes  & 100 & 0   \\[1.5ex]
& No  & 10   & 80 \\ 
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Joey: Few other options now added.

Answer (score 4):

shorter and simpler:

- all `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` are superfluous
- for `\rotatebox` use `origin=center`
- for more vertical (symmetrically distributed) spaces use macro `\makegapedcells` from the package `makecell`. it is needed for spacing rotated word "actual" in `multirow` cell in the first column
- for horizontal lines are used `\cline{2-4}`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{makecell} % for more vertical space in cells
  \setcellgapes{5pt}

  \begin{document}
  {    % for making group where "\makegapedcells" is valid
  \makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{cc|cc}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}
              &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted} \\
      &       &   Yes &   No              \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
  \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}}
      & Yes   & 100   & 0                 \\
      & No    & 10    & 80                \\ 
      \cline{2-4}
      \end{tabular}
   }
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]